# Where to place downloaded ScalaTest jar so sbt uses it across projects?

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

I've downloaded the ScalaTest jar and have used it as in the example, but now I would like to start using it with sbt. Where do I place the downloaded jar so I can use it with sbt across multiple projects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't download dependencies like ScalaTest manually. The point of using sbt is to declare your project's dependencies and let sbt download them for you automatically.

Add this line in your `build.sbt` file:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.0" % "test"
```

For more details see official [doc](http://www.scalatest.org/download) on setting this up.